# ASP.NET Core C# Jquery Datatable Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to fill a jquery datatable by passing an array to it, the controller pass an array of users using `ViewBag` as following:

```
userInfo[] users = _context.userInfo.ToArray();
ViewBag.UsersArray = users;
```

In the view, I used `ViewBag.UsersArray` as a data source for the jquery datatable:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#users').DataTable({
            data: @ViewBag.UsersArray,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'username' },
                { data: 'balance' },
                { data: 'contract_id' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I always got Unexpected token ']'
[image]

Comment: Razor won't take a userInfo[] and automatically convert it to JSON. You'll need to serialize it to JSON yourself.

Comment: @mason serialize the array?

Comment: You can't just assign a userInfo[] array from the ViewBag to a variable in JavaScript. It just doesn't work like that, because ultimately this Razor view is going to be rendered and the results sent to the client. So that's why you see in your screenshot where it says `date: CustomerCare.Models.userInfo[]`. Razor is just performing a .ToString() on the object, and that's the default .ToString() implementation. But if you serialize the userInfo[] to a JSON string, you can then utilize that in your Razor template, and ultimately it will result in a usable object on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use C# objects in script tags in Razor pages, you must first convert them to JSON. Razor does not do this automatically.

This way you can easily serialize your array to JSON:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#users').DataTable({
            data: @Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.UsersArray),
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'username' },
                { data: 'balance' },
                { data: 'contract_id' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to just be that the array is being treated as a reference to an object rather than being enumerated. I would first try wrapping @ViewBag.UsersArray in quotes, and if that makes no difference I would "manually" enumerate through the array in your JS code and add each array element to the table's data property.